# JRE and JDK Paths

Tags: java

I am currently learning coding and Java. I have done lots of research on this topic but I just can't seem to understand it. So I have the JDK 9.0.1 and JRE 9.0.1. As you can see here I have the JRE and JDK 9.0.1 in my Programs and Files folder in my C drive/ SSD:

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to add both the JRE and JDK to the Environment Variables. I have tried numerous things but sometimes I can only get one or the other to work (i.e. java working in CMD but not javac). This is currently what my variable looks like.

[image]

I have tried doing the semicolon then put my other JDK bin folder path but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Don't add both. The JDK includes the JRE, so only add the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin` folder to the PATH. Basically like you show, but the JDK, not the JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you intended to ask about "Java" as opposed to "javascript", there is no need to have both the jdk and the jre.  The jdk contains the jre.

Comment: Andreas beat me to it :)

Comment: Oh ok thanks! But the reason why I was thinking I needed to do both was because I found some issue with my .jar files where I couldn't open them and it said it was because I didn't have a path for JRE. But now I guess I just have to figure out how to fix that problem. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a JAVA_HOME set?